# ASP.NET MVC + Castle ActiveRecord + elmah on Mono 2.6 on windows 7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mono, castle-activerecord, elmah

I am trying to get xsp2 to run my asp.net mvc application, but I get the attached error message with no debug information.  Nothing useful is produced if I run xsp2 with --verbose.

The app runs fine under IIS on Windows Vista and Windows 7 and VS's built in webserver.

I know others have had success with this, so I'm hoping that I just missed something obvious.

Thanks,

**EDIT:  If I remove Castle.ActiveRecord.Linq and NHibernate.Linq, everything works again.  I am not currently using either, so it shouldn't be a big deal to remove them.  Any other suggestions?**

[500 http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/56fc36a5db.png](http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/56fc36a5db.png)

Comment: Try an empty aspx. Do you get the same error?

Comment: OK, so a default project does work, but none of my other projects do.  I'll have to start adding in pieces to see what breaks it.

Comment: I meant try an empty aspx on your project.

Comment: OK, so if I just add an empty aspx to the project and try to browse to that aspx, I get the same, empty error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer (for me) was to remove Castle.ActiveRecord.Linq and NHibernate.Linq as references.  Since I wasn't using Linq, it wasn't a problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it is having trouble compiling something in your app.  You might want to try using VS to pre-compile your app and see if it will run then.

(Use VS's Publish feature to make a pre-compiled version on your local disk, and point xsp2 at it.)